# Filter by selection from referenced table

Tags: vega-lite

I have a single data source within `datasets` that I use in two concatenated charts. Now when I click on a bar in the left chart I would like to filter the right chart. See animated gif:
[image]

But is doesn't.
Click [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6baRHIAmALgBakAsADEwDRS0Fq3WkDMLAL6DW4DnHjQAhrywBtMRFAQVUCjXpYAjC1GqIkAM4EANgWjVkCUjgDKAUQAy9gMIAVG5GoBPAA4FSI2R4VDNIdkgAJwJDWBNcAKxIUNgAIykTSGE9fUhKGSlPeCkAW0SoailUswB9fMqsnNVIEqlIgGtA9MjwxRVIAklYSmD0LGV9AwAPTx9-QPhYEuCM8KgUU0pAgFkpACtYSJqAcUHoxr7m708pVFRo1BlymFgAV3heCLnngEdXqQ+yEqlgSF0mBjgJkOsz8z0Wy2KmQiGxMWySuwOR1O8HOIku-RQJhMAHlfFJoEDruN8c0JCNLNZxkZTOYGfBAg5nO41ngMq9ylo8eD+rg+eUmAA6Pg0sCCfFy1RClQTZrqOikHRsfF5ApFUrPSrVAh1XVK5rUSIAwyIQ4lUhyHCE6gEHpM4xmCxWdlJTmuDzCAC6TX6rQ6XTavUmAyGIxCNhlkBmTO+CyWKyR60IqJ2+0OJzOATNuSpZFu9wIj2dgTg70+FVhgT+AMswOQoKLtLi0OTDaS8PTPJRaKgGLz2Nx8r6CrAQbEOsqxmohnj5qqtXqhXk+JVuTcQLCSRcVCklAIYFPYAAIgRXsvg81R1iC4FL5bWpHwZAXG8PpFvDViUiNBgkCAAhS0AC9kEyeV72wBM92oA8oBcWhYEhJ4sGvAhfCvNp2jAWxzGiJcPyjR98xxZ43FoICiRdAB6Wxb38eBjDI3Jv1rP8AKA1AQKSABJeARkKWDt0gRDkMgAAxZAIMKCIKPHZ5X1KRSUJ-C1-0A4DvSgYTRLBfQd2aKTnjkyJDGoMBHFgBJ2EcKRrLAAAlIEYg4h9cyfKiXzfRSEy438dL4gSoAAVXgDzKEI4FPPEyZTP6czAhk2A4mQQx6DggxlOfQ8lgIShrlyzTuNCvTAiimK4qeZdEpMhD92eQSwF2SIgOKsApDiy0QjPAAFF1YnZMrIHyvzCrKEqvP6YLtN4qqkhq51YtseKGsmacIADMQ5UEIA) to open in the vega-editor. 
Or check the spec here::

```
{
  "config": {"view": {"width": 400, "height": 300}},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "width": 100,
      "selection": {"SELECT": {"type": "single", "resolve": "global"}},
      "data": {"name": "table_data"},
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Major_Genre"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Major_Genre"},
        "fillOpacity": {
          "condition": {"selection": "SELECT", "value": 1},
          "value": 0.3
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 100,
      "data": {"name": "table_data"},
      "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "SELECT"}}],
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Major_Genre"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "Major_Genre"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "datasets": {
    "table_data": [
      {
        "Title": "Cidade de Deus",
        "Major_Genre": "Drama",
        "Country_Origin": "Brazil"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Chocolate: Deep Dark Secrets",
        "Major_Genre": "Thriller/Suspense",
        "Country_Origin": "India"
      },
      {"Title": "Fiza", "Major_Genre": "Drama", "Country_Origin": "India"},
      {
        "Title": "First Love, Last Rites",
        "Major_Genre": "Drama",
        "Country_Origin": "United States"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Foolish",
        "Major_Genre": "Comedy",
        "Country_Origin": "United States"
      },
      {
        "Title": "I Married a Strange Person",
        "Major_Genre": "Comedy",
        "Country_Origin": "United States"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your selections refer to groups of points rather than single points, you need to provide an explicit `fields` or `encodings` argument to specify what points are included in the selection.

In this case, the chart will behave as expected if you specify your selection in one of the following ways:

```
"selection": {"SELECT": {"type": "single", "fields": ["Major_Genre"], "resolve": "global"}}

"selection": {"SELECT": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["color"], "resolve": "global"}}

"selection": {"SELECT": {"type": "single", "encodings": ["x"], "resolve": "global"}}
```

Here's the working chart in action: [(vega editor link)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjMSA3ZApgO6baRHIAmALgBakAsADEwDRS0Fq3WkDMLAL6DW4DnHjQAhrywBtMRFAQVUCjXpYAjC1GqIkAM4EANgWjVkCUjgDKAUQAy9gMIAVG5GoBPAA4FSI2R4VDNIdkgAJwJDWBNcAKxIUNgAIykTcKgUU0pDUjlIAFkpACtYSIB9AHECeGjIAF1hPX1IShkpT3gpAFtEqGopVLNKjqHIEUUVSF6pSIBrQPTI8OmDOrhKYPQsZX0DAA9PH39A+Fhe4IysyByTSkCS8qra+oCpg4NvTylUVGiqBkAxgsAArvBeBFTiCAI5gqSQ5BDSwJSatA6gkwVE5+EEXK49TIRe6PJLPCo1OoNT5fO7IEwmADyvik0GRPz26zaEm2lmseyMpnM-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).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't expect three different answers!